# How to tell if a field of generic type is initialised?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that defines a fluent interface, including an `Else` method, which can only be called once. The problem I therefore have, is how to tell if it has been called. Currently, I'm doing this via an extra bool field:

```
public class FluentMatcher<T1, T2, TResult>
{
    private bool _elseValueSet;
    private TResult _elseValue;

    ...

    public FluentMatcher<T1, T2, TResult> Else(TResult resultIfElseRequired)
    {
        if (_elseValueCalled)
        {
            throw new ElseAlreadyAddedException();
        }
        _elseValue = resultIfElseRequired;
        _elseValueSet = true;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am uncomfortable with this though and so I'm considering something like:

```
public class FluentMatcher<T1, T2, TResult>
{
    private Initialisable<TResult> _elseValue;

    ...

    public FluentMatcher<T1, T2, TResult> Else(TResult resultIfElseRequired)
    {
        if (_elseValue != null)
        {
            throw new ElseAlreadyAddedException();
        }
        _elseValue = new Initialisable<TResult>(resultIfElseRequired);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This raises two questions:

1. Is there already a way to test if the field has been initialised? I'm assuming not, as it could be a struct and thus cannot be null. Did I miss something though?
2. I have a feeling that I'm not really fixing anything with my new version and that I'm playing with semantics. The first version works just fine, I just think it ugly. Is there a good reason to not use a bool in this case?

Comment: My 2 cents: I like your original solution. It's clear, concise, and it works.

Comment: @RoyDictus Thanks for the feedback. I think that dcastro came up with a nice solution though (prevent Else being called through the use of interfaces) so I'm going with that.

Comment: Btw, this technique is also useful for dictating the _order_ in which methods should be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Else` method should return another very similar interface - one that does **not** have an `Else` method, so that you won't be able to call it twice.

Here's an example from an app I was working on.

```
public class AddColumn
{
    internal AddColumn()
    {

    } 

    public NamedAddColumn Named(string name)
    {
        return new NamedAddColumn(name);
    }
}

public class NamedAddColumn
{
    protected string Name {get; set;}

    internal NamedAddColumn(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public VarcharTypedAddColumn Varchar
    {
        get
        {
            return new VarcharTypedAddColumn(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an fluent interface for creating database migrations. As you can see, the `Named` method returns a different class, with a very similar semantic meaning (they both represent a column) - this class, however, does not allow you to "name" the column twice.

This is how you'd use this interface:

```
        db.AlterTable(tb => tb
                                .Named("Users")
                                .AddColumn(column => column
                                                         .Named("age")
                                                         .Integer
                                )
                                .AddColumn(column => column
                                                         .Named("username")
                                                         .Varchar
                                )
```

**Edit**
In your case, you'd have something like this:

```
public class FluentMatcher<T1, T2, TResult>
{
    /*
       Methods A B C

     */

    public FluentMatcherWithElse<T1, T2, TResult> Else(TResult resultIfElseRequired)
    {
        return new FluentMatcherWithElse(resultIfElseRequired);
    }
}

public class FluentMatcherWithElse<T1, T2, TResult>
{
    internal FluentMatcherWithElse(TResult resultIfElseRequired) { ... }

    /*
       Methods A B C - but NO else method

     */
}
```

Comment: That is a really nice idea. I shall use that, thanks.